# FCM token id not generated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not getting FCM token.

On my login screen I am calling this

```
 startService(new Intent(this, FetchNewRefreshToken.class));
        startService(new Intent(this, ContCreateTokenService.class));
```

My manifest

```
 <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".ContCreateTokenService" />
        <service android:name=".FetchNewRefreshToken" />



public class ContCreateTokenService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
}



public class FetchNewRefreshToken extends IntentService {
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */

    public static final String TAG = FetchNewRefreshToken.class.getSimpleName();


    public FetchNewRefreshToken() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {

            // Resets Instance ID and revokes all tokens.
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();


            // Now manually call onTokenRefresh()
            Log.d(TAG, "Getting new token");
           String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            final Intent intents = new Intent("tokenReceiver");
            // You can also include some extra data.
            final LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
            intents.putExtra("token", token);
            broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intents);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {



            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            sendNotification("text");
        }
// Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

My mainActivity class

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(tokenReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter("tokenReceiver"));
    }
BroadcastReceiver tokenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
            //Log.d("token",token);
          // String token=FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            if(token != null)
            {
                //send token to your server or what you want to do
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                Log.d("token",token);
                Firebase reference1 = new Firebase("https://fuudful-1a15c.firebaseio.com/users/" +user.getUid());
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("registrationtoken", token);
                reference1.push().setValue(map);
            }

        }
    };
```

I am not getting the token , the notification is also not generated as well as there is no insert in the database.

Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Check GooglePlayserviceVersion if old version installed then it will create issue with firebase

**Method for Check Google Play Service Version**

```html
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            goahead = false;
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                Log.i("Demo App", "This device is not supported.");

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog_app = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                dialog_app.setTitle("Error");
                dialog_app.setMessage("This device is not supported..");
                dialog_app.setCancelable(false);
                dialog_app.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                dialog_app.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If google play services is old then this method will show update dialog otherwise its returns true and you can call service.

**Check Play service version**

```html
if(checkPlayServices())
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
}
```

**CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService.class** : Service Class for Refesh Token

```html
public class CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**Service Class for fetch FCM Token : RegistrationIntentService.class**

```html
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    // abbreviated tag name
    private static final String TAG = RegistrationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }
    String token;
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Make a call to Instance API

        FirebaseInstanceId instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();

        
        //String senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);

        // request token that will be used by the server to send push notifications
        token = instanceID.getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Registration Token: " + token);

    }
}
```

**Define Services in Manifest file**

```html
<service android:name=".notification.CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

<service
            android:name=".notification.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making Intent service, can you try to use their own service which generates token. Store that into your preference and then use from whenever you want.

```
public class TokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.w("notification", refreshedToken);
    //store token into preference
    }
}
```

Put this lines into your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
   <service
        android:name=".TokenService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

Comment: Is your mobile device have Google play service ?

Comment: why are you creating your own service ? All you need to create two service class which extends firebase provided service class . And you don't need to execute those classes explicitely it will get automatically called.

Comment: Thanks man It works for me but Can you explain me what the service actually did?

Comment: It will register your device token to Firebase. So, your mobile device can get notification. @Nitin Khanna

Comment: I know but same code is there in its parent class onTokenRefresh method@RonakJoshi

Comment: I didn't get your properly. But in Firebase you just have to create this one single service and in onTokenRefresh() method you will get Token which you can send on your server. Hope that this will work for you.